# Comparing two Sub-Strings of two Strings between two set positions (integer values) in C

Tags: c, string, char, substring, connection-string

I have two strings and want to compare them, but between two variables. Example: String a = "stackoverflow" and String b = "stacknotoverflow". I want to check if every char between the 5th position of String a (int = 5 till int =9) and 8th position of String b (int = 8 till int = 12)  position of both strings is the same. Can anyone help me with this simple problem?

Comment: C or C#? Why both tags?

Comment: What have you tried doing and where is the problem?

Comment: I have an array char a[1000][100]. And i am getting back a string:. Now i want to compare them, but only the positions between the 5th and 8th char.

Comment: Reopening.  This question is about comparing internal substrings, not a simple string comparison.

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad" again. OP did not show any attempt.

Comment: Ahh ok so the question is not right??

Comment: And sorry for not being online 24/7 after the question was solved got some IRL stuff as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `strncmp` function to compare two strings up to a maximum number of characters.  To start a comparison in the middle of a string, you would pass in the address of the array element to start the comparison at.

For example:

```
if (strncmp(&string1[4], &string2[4], 4) == 0) {
    printf("characters 5 - 8 are the same\n");
} else {
    printf("characters 5 - 8 are not the same\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping a newbie out :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're talking about C.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp

This function is used to compare strings in C.

```
int result = strcmp(str1, str2);
printf("Compare result: %d", result);
```

Comment: This compares the entire strings, which is not the problem.